# Understanding "Make America Great Again"

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms

Being a non-native speaker, it is tempting to think about this phrase as expressing the utmost respect and esteem for **Great** Britain as the fatherland of whole english-speaking world. Moreover, there could be another explanation. Having left Great Britain they lost "great-ness", and now Trump promises to return it back - make America **great again**.

Can it be true? Could Trump refer to **Great** Britain in the slogan "Make America **Great** Again"? Or it has nothing to do with **Great** Britain, and it is just a coincidence?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What does the adjective ‘[great](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/great)’ in *Make America Great Again* refer to?

- Was President Trump suggesting that the US is now smaller in size?
  No, he wasn't.
- Does it mean that the US used to be called *Great America*?
  No, the appellative *great* (meaning ‘large’) has never been attached to the name of "America" or "The United States". The name **Great Britain** is derived from Middle English *[Bretaygne the Grete](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Great_Britain)*,  so as not to be confused with *Brittany*.
- Was Trump advocating that The United Kingdom should reclaim the US?
  Absolutely not. The US fought and won its independence in 1776, why would it want to return to being a colony of the *United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland*?
- Does the term ‘great’ refer to the **power** and **eminence** of the US in the world?
  Yes, it does.

---

To recap, imagine the following conversation between two friends:

> A: The big dinner party **was** (a) **great** (success) two years ago. But this year it really flopped, none of the guests seemed to have had any fun.
>   B: What about next year?
>   A: I don't know... hosting dinner parties is very time-consuming and expensive affair.
>   B: Don't worry, with my help we can **make** it **great again**.

The slogan *Make America Great Again* ([#MAGA](https://twitter.com/hashtag/maga)) is an ellipsis for "Let's **make America** (The USA) a **great** country **again**. With the not too subtle inference that it was the Democrats who ruined the nation during the eight years of power.

Comment: I think the Trumpsters would say that the decline has been a long time in the making, and that is not to be attributed solely to the previous administration. For example, NAFTA, one of their targets, goes back to the Clinton era.

Answer (score 4):

**It has no meaning**

The thing that America "lost" which they want back to make it "great" has never been defined. It is a slogan which has no meaning at all, but leaves the meaning up to the interpretation of whoever attempts to understand it.

The wikipedia page refers to how Trump made up his slogan:

> Trump himself began using the slogan formally on November 7, 2012, the day after Barack Obama won his reelection against Mitt Romney. He first considered "We Will Make America Great", but did not feel like it had the right "ring" to it.[12] "Make America Great" was his next name, but upon further reflection, he felt that it was a slight to America because it implied that America was never great. After selecting "Make America Great Again", Trump immediately had an attorney register it. (Trump later said that he was unaware of Reagan's use in 1980 until 2015, but noted that "he didn't trademark it".)

The common interpretation of the slogan is that he wants to improve the state of America and make it "great". The reason for the "again" is because without it he implies that America has never been great before.

As for Great Britain, I think that it's safe to assume that the majority of Brits would be offended to have their country's name used by the current president.

Answer (score 0):

"Great" is a commonly used term of approval, as @Mari-Lou A showed.  There is no reason to think that any reference to Great Britain is intended, nor that Trump's audience will believe any such reference is there.

While the original meaning of "great" was "big" (and it can still mean that sometimes), it is probably more common to use it to mean "good", "successful" etc, and this is the meaning intended in Trump's slogan.

Some examples of "great" and its different meanings are found at: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/great

However, it's interesting to note that the MAGA slogan seems to have been preceded by the "Make Britain Great Again" slogan.  On Google Ngrams you can see that the MBGA slogan was used in the 1950s and early 70s, whereas MAGA didn't appear until the mid-70s.  Also, it appears that the British version of the slogan dates back to the 19th century, when it was used by the Conservative politician Disraeli, among others. (See also: http://www.pearsoned.co.uk/bookshop/minds/rexpress/questions/modern-history/8-disraeli-answers.pdf )

Clearly the British slogan is a pun: it refers to Great Britain as a political entity (which is named "Great" on account of its size: it was originally called "great" to contrast it with Ireland, and later to distinguish it from Brittany).  But it also refers to the notion of political greatness (importance on the world stage, economic and diplomatic importance, and originally the Empire, etc).